# Can a Unity XR Quest 2 app detect boundary change from roomscale to stationary?

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculusquest

I'm developing a roomscale game for Quest 2 in Unity using the XR toolkit.  It needs the device to be in roomscale mode with a big enough play area inside the boundary.  I want it to display an error message to the user if they start it in stationary mode or switch to stationary during play.  How can the game detect if the system is in stationary mode?

I've been using the `boundaryChanged` callback of `xrInput` (an instance of `XRInputSubsystem`) to track changes in the boundary polygon when the user redraws the boundary or recenters their view with system menu button long press, and that works fine.  But, to my surprise, the callback is not invoked when switching boundary modes.  The `xrInput.trackingOriginUpdated` callback isn't invoked either.  I tried polling `xrInput.GetTrackingOriginMode()` every frame but it always returns `Floor` regardless.